# Setting background color of a button changes the size of button

Tags: android

I am creating an Alert Dialog on clicking an imageView .Code is given below:

```
imgEditStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_status, null);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

                final EditText edtStatus = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editStatus);

                Button btnOK = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
               // btnOK.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_color)), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String statusText = edtStatus.getText().toString().trim();
                        new UpdateStatusTask().execute(statusText);
                    }
                });

                Button btnCancel = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
                btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

**dialog_edit_status.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin20"
        android:hint="Enter your status here"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding10"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding10"
        android:textColor="@color/black_color"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray_color"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin10"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin10">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin50"
            android:text="OK"
            android:background="@color/orange_color"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin50"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to set orange color in the background of OK button.But its size got changed. I tried to use the following code :

```
btnOK.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_color)), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

it is giving me error :setColorFilter() in Drawable can not be applied to (int) . Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: btnOK.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color)); use this

Comment: Same issue.Still button size increased.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color but retain other styles, then below might help.

```
btnOK.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: It is working but background color of button is different from what i have used

Comment: u can change ur color what ever u want :) like i place R.color.colorAccent you can place here u color R.color.orange_color

Comment: and if it helps you kindly accept the answer as right :) Happy Coding

Comment: I have used tnOK.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(ProfileActivity.this, R.color.orange_color), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);  As you can see i have chosen orange color here but it is changed to different color

Comment: try to set different color and see the output @DeepakR

Comment: Very strange to see here that orange and red color are changed to some different color but blue color is working fine.

Comment: set the value of color which have high alpha and set that color see the difference @DeepakR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110108/discussion-between-deepakr-and-jhaman-das).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
btnOK.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange_color));
```

Answer (score 0):

btnOK.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange_color);